# How could I fade out using jQuery a setTimeout function?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to `fadeOut` an object after some time determined by a `setTimeout` function. I tried this:

```
var timer;
$(window).on('mousemove', function () {
    $("#my_div_id").fadeIn(1900)
    $('#my_div_id').addClass('show');
    try {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    } catch (e) {}
    timer = setTimeout(function () {    
        $('#my_div_id').fadeOut(1900).removeClass('show');   
    }, 5960); 
});
```

Essentially when you don't move the mouse the jQuery hide the `my_div_id`and when you move the mouse it shows the div and correctly does the fade in.

Why the `.fadeOut(1900)` doesn't work?

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/u5ud4f8w/. Check the console for errors elsewhere. Also, just FYI, you don't need the `try` around `clearTimeout()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the fiddle, however in my case doesn't work...and I don't have errors from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it, Not tested.

```
var timer;
$(window).on('mousemove', function () {
$("#my_div_id").fadeIn(1900)
$('#my_div_id').addClass('show');
try {
    clearTimeout(timer);
} catch (e) {}
    timer = setTimeout(function () {    
    $('#my_div_id').fadeOut(1900,function() {   
   $(this).removeClass('show');
    });   
  }, 5960); 
});
```

Comment: Try to understand remove() and removeClass() in jquery

Comment: I don't know why but on my CodeIgniter framework your solution works, not mine. Thanks

Comment: Actually you mistake is here  $('#my_div_id').fadeOut(1900).removeClass('show');

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the same jQuery object and invoking fadein animations, every time the mouse moves, which is not good performance-wise.

So, you can move the opacity to CSS and cache your jQuery object.

```js
var timer,
    $myId = $('#my_div_id');

$(window).on('mousemove', function () {
    $myId.addClass('show');
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {    
        $myId.removeClass('show');
    }, 5960); 
});
```

```css
#my_div_id {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #C00;
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1900ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 1900ms;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1900ms;
    transition: opacity 1900ms;
}

#my_div_id.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div_id"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but I cannot use it in my project, indeed my div is loaded on main template and I need only in one view to fade in/ fade out